# Set hours in week view in calendar

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, calendar

Is there any way to set hours I want to see in Week view in Calendar?
I do not need hours marked with red ellipsis's and need only hours marked with blue rectangle. 
If I try to resize window, then it compresses the whole view, i.e. everything becomes smaller and still shows hours I do not use...
How can I make Calendar to show only specified hours in Week view, which is most convenient in my daily activities - need to see the whole week at once. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Calendar** → **Preferences** → **General** and set **Show 24 hours at a time** to **12**.

Additionally you can set **Day starts at** to automatically scroll to given time.

[image]

Comment: This does not hide morning and night hours from the calendar.